# 'string' does not name a type - c++ error

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

I am new to C++. I was recently making a small program that uses classes in separate file. I also want to use the setter and getter (set & get) functions to assign value to a variable. The compiler gives me a weird error when i run the program. it says 'string' does not name a type. Here is the code:

MyClass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H   // #ifndef means if not defined
#define MYCLASS_H   // then define it
#include <string>

class MyClass
{

public:

   // this is the constructor function prototype
   MyClass(); 

    void setModuleName(string &);
    string getModuleName();


private:
    string moduleName;

};

#endif
```

MyClass.cpp file

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

MyClass::MyClass()  
{
    cout << "This line will print automatically because it is a constructor." << endl;
}

void MyClass::setModuleName(string &name) {
moduleName= name; 
}

string MyClass::getModuleName() {
return moduleName;
}
```

main.cpp file

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MyClass obj; // obj is the object of the class MyClass

    obj.setModuleName("Module Name is C++");
    cout << obj.getModuleName();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::string moduleName;`

Comment: I didn't get it. which file should I modify? can u plz explain step by step.

Comment: I and a lot of other people will strongly recommend against trying to fix this by adding `using namespace std;` to the header. It doesn't always lead to pain, but it causes more grief than you likely want to put up with. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice

Comment: SergeyA's point is that there is no such thing as `string`. But there is `std::string`. You are using the wring name.

Comment: @downvoters Find a good dupe or shut up.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There's a close reason specifically for questions like these... "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the `std::` namespace scope explicitly in your header file:

```
class MyClass {    
public:

   // this is the constructor function prototype
   MyClass(); 

    void setModuleName(std::string &); // << Should be a const reference parameter
                    // ^^^^^
    std::string getModuleName();
 // ^^^^^    

private:
    std::string moduleName;
 // ^^^^^    
};
```

---

In your `.cpp` file you have

```
using namespace std;
```

which is grossly OK, but better should be

```
using std::string;
```

or even better yet, also using the `std::` scope explicitly like in the header.

Comment: Better yet, no `using` at all in .cpp. `std::string` is just fine.

Comment: @SergeyA If its unambiguous it's _grossly OK_ as mentioned.

Comment: What does it mean 'grossly' in this context? *Overall*?

Comment: it now gives me a new error. error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::__cxx11::string& {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&}' from an rvalue of type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'

Comment: @SergeyA I meant, OK for many cases.

Comment: @AjmalKhan Fix how you pass the parameter: `void MyClass::setModuleName(const string &name) {` if you're using temporary constructed (r)values.

Comment: @SergeyA May be [небрежного](https://translate.google.de/?hl=de#en/ru/grossly%20negligent) :-P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, there is a differece between grossly negligent and grossly ok :)

Comment: @SergeyA I've been noticing that of course, that's why I reflected :) ...